# Image not showing in flutter.dart in vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

In my pubspec.yaml file,

### assets: -assets/

----------in my app directory folder---
the assets folder is located in ....E:\recipes\assets

why is my Image not found or loaded in the app?
Image(image: AssetImage('assets/spagetti.jpg'))

question: Where do i put my assets folder(images folder) in the directory?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMvdf.png)

enter image description here

Comment: kindly add a screenshot of pubspec.yaml file. and you can put your assets folder in your root directory

Answer (score 0):

copy and paste the below code exactly as it is in your pubspec.yaml file and replace it with your config:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

spacing is significant when you set your path in this file. this will totally work fine and you are good to go.

Comment: error occured---
[recipes] flutter pub get
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Unexpected child "flutter" found under "flutter".
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at E:\recipes\pubspec.yaml
exit code 1

Comment: same result; image still not showing. my image directory is
e:\recipes\assets\images

code in yaml is
assets: -assets/images/

but the image still not showing. what do I need to do? Thanks

Comment: code:
Widget buildRecipeCard(Recipe recipe) {
  // 1
  return Card(
    // 2
    child: Column(
      // 3
      children: <Widget>[
        // 4
        Image(image: AssetImage(recipe.imageUrl)),
        // 5
        Text(recipe.label),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Comment: class Recipe {
  String label;
  String imageUrl;
  Recipe(this.label, this.imageUrl);

  static List<Recipe> samples = [
    Recipe('Spaghetti and Meatballs', 'spagmeat.jpg'),
    Recipe('Tomato Soup', 'assets/27729023535_a57606c1be.jpg'),
    Recipe('Grilled Cheese', 'assets/3187380632_5056654a19_b.jpg'),
    Recipe('Chocolate Chip Cookies', 'assets/15992102771_b92f4cc00a_b.jpg'),
    Recipe('Taco Salad', 'assets/8533381643_a31a99e8a6_c.jpg'),
    Recipe('Hawaiian Pizza', 'assets/15452035777_294cefced5_c.jpg'),
  ];
}

Comment: flutter: 
  assets:
    - assets/images    just add images after my answer and see if it works

Comment: what is the ideal size of a picture that is accepted in the flutter program? what pixels?
I used 2500x1667. is it the reason the image is not loaded? what's the ideal pixel size?

Comment: there is no ideal size. you can wrap your image in a container with a fixed height and width with whatever size u want to see how it looks. Container(width: 100, height: 100 ,child: YOUR IMAGE HERE)

Comment: i opened the YAML file in notepad. now the YAML file has notepad icon in it.  error occurs when i run without debug. error message appears...
You don't have extension debugging YAML. Should we find a YAML extension in the marketplace?